# HornetQ without JMS and JNDI

Tags: hornetq

I am looking for a simple hornetQ example that does not use JMS, JNDI or the JBoss AS. Most of the examples included in the release use JNDI and JMS, or the JBoss AS. I've looked at the embedded examples, but I don't want to run hornetQ embedded in my application. Could someone please point me in the right directions. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

It was impossible to us to write every single example in core and JMS API, and maintain both working.

For that reason we have included just a few core examples, and the JMS examples.

JMS is just a thin layer on the core-api, and all you probably need to know about the core-api is there on these embedded and core examples.

If you have any specific question about the API, or you're looking for a specific example I can help you with.

Comment: Hi Clebert. I am new to HornetQ and I know there is a lot to learn. I don't expect all the examples to be in JMS and core. I was only looking for a **single** example that was without JMS and not embedded. Unless I'm wrong (please point this out if I am), it looks like all the core examples are embedded. I eventually found this [link](https://community.jboss.org/thread/176446) that helped me bit, but I would have liked to find a example from you guys. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the examples of chapter 3 of the new HornetQ book

[www.amazon.com/dp/1849518408/?tag=packtpubli-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849518408)